# Javascript Node.js Unicode Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, unicode, xregexp

I need input validation, good input validation to keep everything clean. So I want a strict regular expression on "full name", international so I need Unicode support. I downloaded XRegExp, which compiles "their format" to regular expressions and supports Unicode however:

Correct names:

- John Elkjærd
- André Svenson
- Marco d'Almeida
- Kristoffer la Cour

Incorrect names:

- Hans
- H4nn3 Andersen
- Martin Henriksen!

So I need:

1. Match unicode letter (a, æ)
2. Match unicode accents (á, Ë etc.)
3. Match unicode hyphens (- _ etc)

In PHP I can do the following operations to match:

```
\p{L} (unicode letter)
\p{Mn} (unicode accents)
\p{Pd} (unicode hyphens)
```

What I figured out, that I can do with XRegExp:

^\p{L}+$ would match '日本' so only the letter one works, but how can I figure out how to do these unicode accents, hypens?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please refer to [this illuminating article](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). You are going to disallow legitimate names like [N!xau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C7%83xau), for example.

Comment: @lanzz Then there is a logic choice involved: there are more people creating fake accounts under "23780f''asdf[qwerioafbh" than people with a name that doesn't match unicode and a decent regex as such.

Comment: Consider this then: do you really want to prevent some of your legitimate users from actually entering their own legal names? People tend to have strong feelings about their identity, accusing somebody of having an "invalid" name will not encourage any warm feelings towards your site. And trust me, people who want to create fake accounts are very capable of thinking of fake names that still pass whatever hoops you ask them to jump through.

Comment: @lanzz You are right. And email activation verifies their identity anyway. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like @lanzz gave you some good feedback about potential issues with name validation, but for the record, you can use the Unicode categories you mentioned with XRegExp just as you would with PHP. E.g., `XRegExp('^[\\p{L}\\p{Mn}\\p{Pd} ]+$')`. This requires XRegExp's Unicode Categories addon. Note that the backslashes are escaped due to JavaScript string literal escaping rules.